# Send POST to HTML website

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm searching for the best solution to send some data to a html website in my app. I got some variables in my program in the following format:

```
1       var1
2       var2
3       var3
4       var4
5       var5
```

and so on. Nothing more then that. What is the best way to send this to a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is describe simple example with `POST` method.(*How can pass data by `POST` method*)

You can use the following code snippet, as described [in this article](http://panditpakhurde.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/posting-data-to-url-in-objective-c/):

Here, I simple describe how can use of POST method.

> **1.** Set post string with actual username and password.
>
> ```
> NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Username=%@&Password=%@",@"username",@"password"];
> ```
>
> **2.** Encode the post string using `NSASCIIStringEncoding` and also the post string you need to send in NSData format.
>
> ```
> NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
> ```
>
> You need to send the actual length of your data. Calculate the length
>   of the post string.
>
> ```
> NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
> ```
>
> **3.** Create a Urlrequest with all the properties like `HTTP` method, http header field with length of the post string. Create `URLRequest`
>   object and initialize it.
>
> ```
> NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
> ```
>
> Set the Url for which your going to send the data to that request.
>
> ```
> [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abcde.com/xyz/login.aspx"]]];
> ```
>
> Now, set **HTTP** method (*POST or GET*). Write this lines as it is in
>   your code.
>
> ```
> [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
> ```
>
> Set `HTTP` header field with length of the post data.
>
> ```
> [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
> ```
>
> Also set the Encoded value for HTTP header Field.
>
> ```
> [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
> ```
>
> Set the `HTTPBody` of the urlrequest with postData.
>
> ```
> [request setHTTPBody:postData];
> ```
>
> **4.** Now, create URLConnection object. Initialize it with the URLRequest.
>
> ```
> NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
> ```
>
> It returns the initialized url connection and begins to load the data
>   for the url request. You can check that whether you `URL` connection
>   is done properly or not using just **if/else** statement as below.
>
> ```
> if(conn)
> {
> NSLog(@”Connection Successful”)
> }
> else
> {
> NSLog(@”Connection could not be made”);
> }
> ```
>
> **5.** To receive the data from the HTTP request , you can use the delegate methods provided by the URLConnection Class Reference.
>   Delegate methods are as below.
>
> ```
> - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
> ```
>
> Above method is used to receive the data which we get using post
>   method.
>
> ```
> - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
> ```
>
> This method , you can use to receive the error report in case of
>   connection is not made to server.
>
> ```
> - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
> ```
>
> The above method is used to process the data after connection has made
>   successfully.

**Also Refer** [This](http://deusty.blogspot.in/2006/11/sending-http-get-and-post-from-cocoa.html) **and** [This](http://yuvarajmanickam.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/nsurlconnection-basics-for-ios-beginners/) **documentation** for `POST` method.

And here is best example with source code of [HTTPPost Method.](http://kemal.co/index.php/2012/02/fetching-data-with-getpost-methods-by-using-nsurlconnection/)

Comment: have you some knowledgement of serverside script languages?